# Parsing PCAP in Python 2.6

Tags: python, pcap

I am trying to simply parse through data in a packet capture.  I've taken examples just to see if I could compile and I end up with an error.  Below is the code.

```
import dpkt
import sys

f = open('test.pcap')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

for ts, buf in pcap:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    ip = eth.data
    tcp = ip.data


f.close()
```

The error I get is the following:File "inspection.py", line 15, in  tcp = ip.data

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `eth.data` is a string. there is no `data` attribute to strings. Trying `print`ing `ip`

Comment: `scapy` is a better option for this kind of thing than `dpkt`.

Answer (score 3):

The call to `dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)` returned a string because the Ethernet class was unable to unpack `buf`. A likely cause for this is that your pcap file does not have ethernet as its layer 2 protocol. You can load the pcap into Wireshark to confirm this.

The following script attempts to check the datalink field of the pcap file and use an appropriate layer 2 dpkt class to decode the frame:

```
import dpkt
import sys

f = open('test.pcap')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

for ts, buf in pcap:
    if pcap.datalink() == dpkt.pcap.DLT_LINUX_SLL:
        l2 = dpkt.sll.SLL(raw_pkt)
    else:
        l2 = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    ip = l2.data
    tcp = ip.data
```

Comment: You should probably only call `dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet` if `pcap.datalink()` returns `dpkt.pcap.DLT_EN10MB`.  There are [a *lot* of possible link-layer header types](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) and you should check for all the types you support and fail if the type isn't one of those.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve the problem was:

```
        if ip.p == 6:
           tcp = dpkt.tcp.TCP(ip.data)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then flag / vote to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.* Duplicate answer found [here](//stackoverflow.com/a/39583474/2747593).